# rpy2 error when returning from a function - RNULLType not iterable

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm loving rpy2 but I've hit a snag running a function from Rand Wilcox's robust stats package.

For some reason, when I run the function I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'rpy2.rinterface.RNULLType' object is not iterable
```

I'm fairly certain that I'm using the function correctly as it simply takes some integers and a dataframe (or list of lists, or array) as arguments.

#### Here is a reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import random
import numpy as np
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
from urllib.request import urlopen  
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
pandas2ri.activate()

url = urlopen('https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/239/docs/Rallfun-v35.txt')
string = b''.join(url.readlines()).decode()
wilcox = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "wilcox")

data=[list(np.random.normal(0, 1, 50))]*6
wilcox.bbmcppb(2,3,data)
```

As you can see there are some nulls being returned and also some other data seem to be there. 
    TypeError: 'rpy2.rinterface.RNULLType' object is not iterable

```
R object with classes: ('list',) mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7f0e889dba08 / R:0x9a7bec8>
[ListVector, Matrix, Matrix, Matrix]
R object with classes: ('list',) mapped to:
<ListVector - Python:0x7f0e889dba08 / R:0x9a7bec8>
[ListVector, Matrix, Matrix, Matrix]
  Fac.A: <class 'rpy2.robjects.vectors.Matrix'>
  R object with classes: ('matrix',) mapped to:
<Matrix - Python:0x7f0e889da948 / R:0xaf6ec80>
[1.000000, NA_real_, NA_real_, 0.050000, NA_real_, NA_real_

.
.
.
```

The odd thing is that if I assign it to an output variable, it doesn't crash, until I inspect it:

#### no crashing

```
output=wilcox.bbmcppb(2,3,data)
```

#### crashing (with the above error)

```
output=wilcox.bbmcppb(2,3,data)
output
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. The output was stored in a variable `result` which showed 
`TypeError: 'rpy2.rinterface.RNULLType'`. But the output I needed was in `result[0]` which I exported to a csv file by `result[0].to_csvfile('result.csv')`.The exception was being raised by `result[1]`.

You can try that if you are trying to solve a problem. Some discussion on this issue could be found on https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/388/sequence_to_vector-does-not-accept-empty